# Why can't I upload a file using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am unable to upload a picture using all the suggested code from the Internet. Here is the HTML of my upload area:

[image]

I have added dev dependency also

```
//In package.json file:

 "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^3.8.3",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^3.5.3"
  }
```

upload a file code :

```
import 'cypress-file-upload' 
//Upload a file 

const fileName = 'abc.txt'

cy.fixture(fileName).then((fileContent) => {
  cy.get('#root > div > div.root-container.showNotificationsBanner > div.app.modalOpened > div.modal-window.small.msg_composer > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.composerBlock.attachFiles > div > div.btn-addnew')
    .wait(3000)
    .upload({
      fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'input[type=text]',
    },
    {
      subjectType: 'drag-n-drop',
    },
    )
  cy.wait(3000)
})
```

I don't get any errors, but it doesn't upload.

Comment: `'input[type=text]'` doesn't seem like a valid [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type), or even the correct selector for the input you're trying to upload to. Also `upload` doesn't seem like it's part of the API of [the library you're using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload), which uses `attachFile`

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.fixture(fileName).then((fileContent) => {
  cy.get('[type="file"]')
    .attachFile({
      fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'text/plain',
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? How does this solve the problem?

Comment: Read the documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload